# Lazy loading should load data when is needed

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Well, in my concept (correct me if i wrong) the lazy loading should work like that:

Imagine i have a object "Sell" and another "Itens", where i can do it: sell.getItens() or sell.setItens(), just for ilustrate. So, when i use the SQL sentence i just load the SELL without itens, like this: "SELECT * FROM SELL".

But in some place of my code when i try to do: "sell.getItens().get(0).getPrice()", the JPA/Hibernate must load immediatly all itens from Sell, because this is a "demand loading".

Am i correct ? If yes, this is don't work with me.

EDIT 1:
To be more specific, the error occurr when i try use my "itens" in dataTable in JSF, look the code:

```
<p:dataTable rowKey="#{item.id}" var="item"
                            value="#{consultaMB.consulta.itens}"
                            emptyMessage="Não foi encontrado nenhum registro"
                            id="dataTableItensConsulta"
                            selection="#{consultaMB.itemConsulta}" selectionMode="single"
                            rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
                            rowStyleClass="#{(rowIndex mod 2) eq 0 ? 'first-row' : 'second-row'}">
```

The error is: rowKey="#{item.id}": Property 'id' not found on type org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet

EDIT 2: 
This is my complete "Consulta" class, with itens.

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries(value = {
        @NamedQuery(name = "Consulta.findByOrcamento", query = "SELECT c FROM Consulta c "
                + "JOIN FETCH c.orcamento "
                + "JOIN FETCH c.situacao "
                + "WHERE c.orcamento.id = :idOrcamento "
                + "ORDER BY c.dataHoraAgendada desc"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Consulta.findItensByConsulta", query = "SELECT c.itens FROM Consulta c "
                + "JOIN c.itens " + "WHERE c.id = :idConsulta"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Consulta.findAllCompleto", query = "SELECT c FROM Consulta c "
                + "JOIN FETCH c.orcamento "
                + "JOIN FETCH c.situacao "
                + "ORDER BY c.dataHoraAgendada desc") })
@Table(name = "consulta")
public class Consulta extends AbstractBean {

    public Consulta() {
        this.itens = new HashSet<ItemOrcamento>();
        this.itensConcluidos = new HashSet<ItemOrcamento>();
        this.fotos = new ArrayList<FotoConsulta>();
    }

    @Transient
    public static final String FIND_BY_ORCAMENTO = "Consulta.findByOrcamento";
    @Transient
    public static final String FIND_ALL_COMPLETO = "Consulta.findAllCompleto";
    @Transient
    public static final String FIND_ITENS_BY_CONSULTA = "Consulta.findItensByConsulta";

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_orcamento")
    private Orcamento orcamento;

    @Column(name = "data_hora_agendada")
    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dataHoraAgendada;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = javax.persistence.FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "item_consulta", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_consulta") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_item_orcamento") })
    private Set<ItemOrcamento> itens;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = javax.persistence.FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "item_concluido_consulta", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_item_orcamento", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_consulta", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    private Set<ItemOrcamento> itensConcluidos;

    @Column
    private String observacoes;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_situacao")
    private SituacaoConsulta situacao;

    @Column(name = "motivo_reagendamento")
    private String motivoReagendamento;

    @Column(name = "motivo_cancelamento")
    private String movitoCancelamento;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "consulta", targetEntity = FotoConsulta.class)
    @Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
    private List<FotoConsulta> fotos;

    public Orcamento getOrcamento() {
        return orcamento;
    }

    public void setOrcamento(Orcamento orcamento) {
        this.orcamento = orcamento;
    }

    public Date getDataHoraAgendada() {
        return dataHoraAgendada;
    }

    public void setDataHoraAgendada(Date dataHoraAgendada) {
        this.dataHoraAgendada = dataHoraAgendada;
    }

    public Set<ItemOrcamento> getItens() {
        return itens;
    }

    public void setItens(Set<ItemOrcamento> itens) {
        this.itens = itens;
    }

    public void addItem(ItemOrcamento item) {
        this.itens.add(item);
    }

    public void removeItem(ItemOrcamento item) {
        this.itens.remove(item);
    }

    public String getObservacoes() {
        return observacoes;
    }

    public void setObservacoes(String observacoes) {
        this.observacoes = observacoes;
    }

    public SituacaoConsulta getSituacao() {
        return situacao;
    }

    public void setSituacao(SituacaoConsulta situacao) {
        this.situacao = situacao;
    }

    public String getMotivoReagendamento() {
        return motivoReagendamento;
    }

    public void setMotivoReagendamento(String motivoReagendamento) {
        this.motivoReagendamento = motivoReagendamento;
    }

    public String getMovitoCancelamento() {
        return movitoCancelamento;
    }

    public void setMovitoCancelamento(String movitoCancelamento) {
        this.movitoCancelamento = movitoCancelamento;
    }

    public List<FotoConsulta> getFotos() {
        return fotos;
    }

    public void setFotos(List<FotoConsulta> fotos) {
        this.fotos = fotos;
    }

    public void addFoto(FotoConsulta foto) {
        this.fotos.add(foto);
    }

    public void removerFoto(FotoConsulta foto) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.fotos.size(); i++) {
            if (this.fotos.get(i).getFoto().equals(foto.getFoto())) {
                this.fotos.remove(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public Set<ItemOrcamento> getItensConcluidos() {
        return itensConcluidos;
    }

    public void setItensConcluidos(Set<ItemOrcamento> itensConcluidos) {
        this.itensConcluidos = itensConcluidos;
    }

    public void addItemConcluido(ItemOrcamento item) {
        this.itensConcluidos.add(item);
    }

    public void removeItemConcluido(ItemOrcamento item) {
        this.itensConcluidos.remove(item);
    }

}
```

EDIT 3: 
Well, i change my dataTable to :

```
<p:dataTable rowKey="#{item.id}" var="item"
                            value="#{consultaMB.consulta.itensAsList}"
```

And i created the method "getItensAsList()" in Consulta class, and everything works fine. Look:

```
 public List<ItemOrcamento> getItensAsList(){
        List<ItemOrcamento> itensAsList = new ArrayList<ItemOrcamento>();
        Iterator<ItemOrcamento> it = itens.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext())
            itensAsList.add(it.next());

        return itensAsList;
    }
```

I really didn't know that dataTable just accept "List" type in your value attribute.

Comment: How does it not work for you? Does an exception occur?

Comment: i edited my post with some more details.

Answer (score 0):

That's only true if your object is still in managed state.

If not, you first have to merge it to re attached it to an persistence context so that's all lazy properties will be loaded while using getter(s). Else you will have NullPointerException at runtime.

Basically as long as you stay in your transaction your object should stay managed. If you leave it and then try to use again your object in another transaction (or not), you have to merge it so that it's up to date if another process updated it into your database - or if you updated properties of this object.

Please refers to the schema in this answer to have a global overview of the lifecycle:
[How to know if a detached JPA entity has already been persisted or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779857/how-to-know-if-a-detached-jpa-entity-has-already-been-persisted-or-not)

Comment: i think is very strange because the error posted in my post ocurr even if i try create a new object.

Answer (score 0):

The exception you refer to has nothing to with lazy loading. You have not defined the appropriate field id in your class PersistentSet with the necessary getter and setter methods.

Comment: But i have sure that this field exists

Comment: Can you add the class listing to the post please?

Comment: But i think that i discovered the real problem: I'm using "getItens()" as HashSet in my dataTable Jsf, and this don't work. When i try "getItensAsList()" all works fine.

Comment: But in your XHTML, item refers to the class ItemOrcamento. Does it contain an id field?

Comment: Yes, i have sure the ItemOrcamento contains "id".